# Does PHP handle multi-dimension $_REQUEST arrays?

Tags: php, http, forms, multidimensional-array, request

A great feature of PHP is that it handles arrays in request variables, so if you post a string like `...&test[one]=two&test[three]=four` then you can access `test` as an array by using `$_REQUEST['test']`.

However I've discovered today that there's a problem with multi-dimension `$_REQUEST` arrays, and I'm wondering if there's a way around it.

To test, I used a form with the fields:

```
<input name="one[one]" />
<input name="one[two]" />
<input name="three[four[five]]" />
<input name="three[four[six]]" />
```

Once this was submitted, I used `var_dump` to see the array structure:

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["one"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["two"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["three"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["four[five"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["four[six"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

The `one` element is array-ified as expected. But the `three` element is not. Now I wouldn't mind if it just wasn't supported, but what's got me confused is the reason why. Look at the names of the sub-elements of `three` - `four[five` and `four[six`. It's not being interpreted as an array because for some reason the trailing `]` which would help to identify these elements as array values has been lost!

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Is there any way around it, other than to only use a maximum of one level in `$_REQUEST` arrays?

Comment: Please, stop using $_REQUEST. It is harmful.

Comment: @teresko: Please stop posting that. It's not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `three[four][five]` and `three[four][six]` instead.

Comment: I still don't understand why the trailing `]` was getting dropped though.

Comment: Obviously it's due to how PHP is parsing the string.  Exactly why, I don't know.  It's not something that I consider worth my while to open up PHP's source to find out.  Just use the correct format and also be aware of dots in field names. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Answer (score 0):

The input names correspond completely to variable "names".

You'd write in PHP:

```
$three['four']['five'] = 'trees';
```

Likewise in your HTML:

```
<input name="three[four][five]" value="trees" />
```